# emulator app crashes when trying to connect with jsoup in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

There are no errors when running and compiling the code in android studio, but after pressing the button to connect with jsoup the app just crashes for some reason. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    class JsoupParseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

        protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return doc;
        }
    }

    public void connect(View v) {

        // Call from here, it will execute doInBackground
        new JsoupParseTask().execute();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add your stack trace for crash?

Comment: your stack trace?

Comment: @Whales_Corps the answer below helped, I just need an answer for my last comment on the answer below. if you can answer it that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply an exception typed ***NetworkOnMainThreadException***, that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

As for example, try to run your code in AsyncTask:

```
class JsoupParseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;
    }

    @Override    
    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) { 
        // execution of result here 

        String title = doc.title();
    }

}
```

And call this like below:

```
public void connect(View v) {

    // Call from here, it will execute doInBackground
    new JsoupParseTask().execute();
}
```

Besides this don't forget to add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

*But since `AsyncTask` is deprecated, you could try it's alternative. Here is a nice [tutorial](https://medium.com/code-yoga/some-great-alternatives-for-asynctasks-e8113747673a) that mentioned some alternatives of `AsyncTask`*

Comment: How does this connect to the button that I'm using to connect?

Comment: like i don't see public void (view v) that's where the button is suppose to be clicked and it connects.

Comment: Check my updated answer and for more about AsynsTask, please check any tutorial on that. Thanks

Comment: It crashed again. I updated the code above with your new code.

Comment: also there is nothing in the logCat, do you know where I can see the stack trace for android studio?

Comment: Did you add internet permission in `AndroidManifest` xml?

Comment: No. where is AndroidManifest xml, and how do I add internet permission to it?

Comment: Check the link to find out `AndroidManifest.xml`: https://help.dropsource.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/05/android-manifest.png

Comment: Ok I added the internet permission to it. Now that it does new JsoupParseTask().execute(); how do I make it so I can do something like Document newDoc = new JsoupParseTask().execute(); so I can use newDoc.title() to see the title of the website I connected to?

Comment: You have to do it inside `onPostExecute` in AsyncTask. Check my updated answer and debug your code to see result. Thanks

Comment: Hey I have another question here that's related to this question if you don't mind taking a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605699/how-to-wrap-a-method-around-an-async-section-of-code