# How to wrap a method around an async section of code

Tags: java, class, methods, jsoup

How do I wrap a method around this Async section of codes so I can get the variable "doc" returned as a returned value so I can reuse this method? I can't declare a static method inside this class, and when I tried to use a void method, the variable "doc" can't be returned, and there's also errors in the code.

```
class JsoupParseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

        protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org//").get();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return doc;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Document 
   result) {
        // Use here
    }
```

Comment: What am I supposed to put inside //use here? I want to write a method that passes the link in the parameter to the Jsoup.connect, and then returns the "doc" after the method is called so the method can be reused.